# Apache Connection Limit Windows + Linux

Tags: linux, windows, apache

Is there any module for Apache or standard configuration that limit connection speed and satisfy :

- works on Windows + Linux.
- up to date with latest Apache version.
- only limit connection speed, nothing fancier.

I have view `mod_bw`, `mod_mod_cband`, `mod_bandwidth` but it appears none of them support latest Apache version on Windows.

If the above modules will work on windows is there any site to download the binary that works with latest Apache.

Comment: _Why_ do you think those modules do not work for your apache server version?

Comment: I try to install mod_bw but apache wont start, and they seem outdated, is there any link for windows binary, thanks.

Comment: Please take a look at your http servers error log file to find out the _exact_ issue. "Won't start" is a bit vague...

Comment: Typically you need to have files that are binary compatible, so have been compiled based on the same library versions. Either you get them from the same provider / repository, or you need to self compile a version matching your apache server.

Answer (score 0):

after searching the web, I have came around this page [Mod Bandwidth for Apache 2.4.x](https://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx), which contains the binary for mod_bw, tested successfully on Windows Apache 2.4.25